# Let $\{K_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ a decreasing sequence of compact and non-empty sets on $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Then $\cap_{i = 1}^{\infty} K_i \neq \emptyset.$

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Let $\{K_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ a decreasing sequence of compact and non-empty sets on $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Then $\cap_{i = 1}^{\infty} K_i \neq \emptyset.$

I heard about a proof that take $x_i \in K_i.$ Then I have constructed a sequence. It is bounded because for every $i$, $x_i \in K_1$ that is bounded. Then there is a subsequence that converges. That is where I stopped. What indeed means that a subsequence converges? And why does the limit of such subsequence is in every $K_i,$ showing that such intersection is not empty.

Thank you!

Comment: The limit point must belong to every $K_i$. Try to prove it by contradiction.

Comment: a "proof" without contradiction: each $K_i$ is compact and thus closed. Let $(x_{i_k})_{k\ge 1}$ be the converging subsequence with limit $x$, then $(x_{i_k})_{k\ge 1}$ is contained by $K_{i_1}$ and thus also $x$ due to closeness. Thus $x\in K_{i_1} \subseteq \dotsb \subseteq K_1$. Now the sequence $(x_{i_k})_{k\ge 2}$ is contained by $K_{i_2}$, and so on...

Comment: @user251257, why does $(x_{i_k})_{k \ge 1}$ is contained in $K_{1}$ and why this implies that $(x_{i_k})_{k \ge 2}$ is contained in $K_{i_2}$? And what are you trying to conclude? If you can make an answer I will be very thankful.

Comment: @user: $x_i \in K_i$ and the $K_i$'s are decreasing. That is $K_1 \supseteq K_2 \supseteq \dotsb$.

Comment: @user251257 I got it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $i\in \mathbb N$ let $x_i\in K_i$, since $K_i$ is non-empty.
As the sequence $K_1 \supseteq K_2 \supseteq \dotsb$ is decreasing. It follows $(x_i)_{i\ge 1}$ is contained by $K_1$.
By compactness of $K_1$ it follows $(x_i)_{i\ge 1}$ has a converging subsequence $(x_{i_k})_{k\ge 0}$ with limit $x$.

For each $n\in\mathbb N$ the subsequence $(x_{i_k})_{k\ge n}$ starting with $i_n$ is contained by $K_{i_n}$, which is closed. Thus, the limit $x$ is also contained by $K_{i_n} \subseteq \dotsb \subseteq K_1$.
As $i_n\to\infty$ for $n\to\infty$, it follows $x\in K_i$ for each $i\in\mathbb N$, that is $x\in\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb N} K_i$.

Comment: I am confused with one thing: It is clear that $x \in K_{i_n}$.... But, why did you choose $(x_{i_k})_{k \ge n}$? And how could you conclude that $x \in K_i$ for every $i$? Could you be more explicit?

Comment: @user: if I only consider the subsequence starting with say $i_1$ then, I only know that $x\in K_{i_1}$. Thus, I consider every possible start index $i_n$. Now, fix $i\in\mathbb N$. From $i_k\to\infty$ follows there is some $n$ such that $i_n \ge i$ and thus $x\in K_{i_n} \subseteq K_i$.

Comment: thank you! Now it makes sense.